# passing data from jsp to servlet from html table

Tags: html, jsp, session, servlets

I am developing a web application using JSP and Servlets.
In that application I have to show data from database table stud(studID, name, add) in  html table, And each row in the table will have a hyperlink associated with it at the last column. After clicking on that hyperlink I wants to get the (studID) from the table...

so far I have done getting the data from database and then putting it into the column and then adding hyperlink for each row.. But I am not able to get the (studID) from the html table associated with hyperlink..

Thanks in advance....

Source code :

```
<% 
String[][] data = (String[][])request.getAttribute("data"); 
String[] cNames = (String[])request.getAttribute("columnNames"); 
//headings 
%> 
<table> 
<tr> 
<% 
for(int i=0;i<cNames.length;i++) { 
%> 
<th>
<%= cNames[i] %>
</th>
<% 
} 

//data if(data!=null) 
for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++) { 
%>
<tr> 
<% 
for(int a=0;a<3;a++) {
%> 
<td>
<%= 
data[i][a] 
%>
</td> 
<% 
//hyperlink 
if(a==2) { 
%> 
<td>
<a href="PlanProtocol" id=<%=i%> onclick="<% session.setAttribute("ID","p2"); %>" >Edit</a></td> 
<% 
} 
} 
%>
</tr> 
<% } %> 
<tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you show us some code we would be more able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the id as a query string in the url. Simply:

```
  <a href="myservlet?id=<%=stuid%>">My Link</a>
```

Will work. But if you are using JSTL or another tag library then you can do something like this:

```
  <c:url value="/myservlet" var="myURL">
     <c:param name="id" value="1234"/>
  </c:url>

  <a href="<c:out value="myURL">mylink</a>
```

And this has its advantages such as url encoding etc.

---

So to add the id to the URL in your posted code you can:

```
  <a href="PlanProtocol?id=<%=i%>" >Edit</a>
```

And the url will end up like this: `PlanProtocol?id=1234`.

In the Servlet you can get the Parameter by:

```
   request.getParameter("i");
```

However, as I mentioned above, you probably want to use a tag library like the JSTL rather than placing these scriptlets in your page. There are several advantages.

Answer (score 1):

think you should pull out the studID in JSP and format the studID into the query string of the URL, html page. (?studID=xxxxx) So the servlet will know the studID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.setAttribute("studID","value");` in your jsp page to set the value and use `request.getAttribute("studID");` in servlet to get value